# Why input from user is being echoed on terminal?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, select

I am trying to understand program using select() from beej.

When I am pressing a key, program prints "A key was pressed". However, after program exits, the same key is echoed on terminal and I get error "Command not found". Why the key that is pressed is being echoed onto terminal?

Source code :

```
/*
 * select.c demo
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define STDIN 0

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    struct timeval tv;
    fd_set readfds;

    tv = (struct timeval){0};
    tv.tv_sec = 2;
    tv.tv_usec = 5000000;

    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(STDIN, &readfds);

    select(STDIN + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

    if ( FD_ISSET(STDIN, &readfds)){
        printf("A key was pressed\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Timed Out!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
shilpa@shilpa-VirtualBox:Socket_Programming$
shilpa@shilpa-VirtualBox:Socket_Programming$ ./select 
f
A key was pressed
shilpa@shilpa-VirtualBox:Socket_Programming$ f
f: command not found
```

Comment: Please paste the code as well as the output, right here as text.

Comment: Well, you're not `read()`ing the "key", only detecting input availability. The "key" remains in the input buffer.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi : That I understood ... But why it is getting printed on terminal(stdout) ?

Comment: As @PSkocik says, the shell sees unread input, and it's its job to output it on its command line (on *NIX you can input something while a command is running, and that something is expected to be included in the shell's command line after the command has finished running).

Comment: Thank you so much @FrédéricHamidi

Answer (score 1):

Your program doesn't consume anything from its `stdin`.
It only checks if reading from `stdin` would succeed in the time allotted.
Consequently, in term of input consumption, it behaves like:

```
$ sleep 2.5
```

If you run that and type `f<enter>`, then with default terminal settings (controllable with `stty`) it gets echoed (the terminal normally echoes everything you type, unless you turn this off, e.g., for password input), then reechoed when `sleep` terminates at which point your shell receives it. The shell then does what shells do -- try to execute it. This fails, resulting in the `command not found` error message.

Answer (score 0):

In short words - you didn't read anything from terminal in your program. You just wait readiness for read. Detailed explanation below.

**Details**

The main question how output from your program comes to terminal program (like konsole or xterm etc.) and how keys you pressed come to you program.

In short words there there is two bound devices:

1. Terminal master - this device is used by terminal program to show results of running program
2. Terminal slave - this device is used by some program like bash.

stdin is file descriptor in your program that bound to terminal slave device.

When you press the key in terminal program (I skip some steps related to terminal master specific things like termios):

- this symbol is written to terminal master device
- terminal master device passes symbol to terminal slave device
- terminal slave device switch to ready for read state
- stdin file descriptor changes state to "ready for read"
- select finishes and your program writes "A key was pressed"
- your program is finished (it doesn't read anything from device)
- shell program begin reads from the terminal slave (because it is ready for read) and receive input "f" and enter
- shell program interprets f and enter as start program "f"